# CORS in rails controller in before_filter or after_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, http-headers, cors

is there any particular reason (except possibility of header override) that in this article author uses after_filter for setting headers: http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By modifying the headers in an `after_filter` you ensure that the headers set in the `after_filter` are the headers that will be served up; they won't be overridden by your action methods (accidentally or otherwise).

In the case of your article, they're also 'short circuiting' the `before_filter` when the request is found to be the "preflight check" CORS initially makes.

They keep the headers found in the `cors_set_access_control_headers` method separate for readability, but also to help ensure none of those headers **are** set when the request is found to be the "preflight check". During this preflight check, the `before_filter` kills the request, preventing the `after_filter` from executing; which would otherwise override those set in the preflight check.